# Importing Multiple Excel Tables Inside a Worksheet to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, import

I am trying to import multiple tables that are in the same Excel worksheet into separate SQL tables. The problem is that these tables are just separated by format (margins and blank spaces between them). Is there a way that I can import them? The tables all have the same number of columns (6 cols), but the number of rows varies.  [Here is an example of two of such tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ9h8.png)

Comment: Sure, depends on what level of "quality" process you're prepared to accept and what software you have available. What SQL rdbms are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: I just need the values and column names. As for the header (which is a merged cell, it would be good if that value becomes the name of the SQL table. I am using MySQL